# Not able to convert IIdentity to WindowsIdentity in F#

Tags: f#

I have below code in C#. And It is working Good.

```
WindowsIdentity winId = (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = winId.Impersonate();
ctx.Undo();
```

But i am tring to convert this code in F#. I have written below code.

```
Let winId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity :> WindowsIdentity //Showing error
Let ctx = winId.Impersonate()
ctx.Undo()
```

In above code `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` is not able cast in `WindowsIdentity`. Please let me know how can I do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the upcasting (`:>`) operator when you want to use the downcasting (`:?>`) operator.  Upcasting is checked at compile time since you can always know if you can cast up the inheritance hierarchy, but casting down the hierarchy can fail, so it has a separate operator which can fail at runtime.